# Which version on Acer travel mate 8371

Tags: system-installation

I have an old Acer travelmate 8371 with 1.4ghz processor. Which version of ubuntu, xubuntu or lubuntu would one recommend? Or is this too old a laptop? Thanks

Comment: This seems a rather old notebook. If it is only 2 GB it will be rather painful to use it. You have two options for 32 bit OS. First try 18.04 and if it fails try 16.04. You know that these LTS releases are supported only for 5 years and there is no 32 bit release for 20.04.

Comment: Some quick searching indicates that it's a 2 core, 64 bit CPU. It also seems you can go all the way to 8 GB of RAM. Add RAM and an SSD and you can passably run any modern Ubuntu flavor. As it stands, I'd look at Lubuntu 18.04 LTS. If you like it, buy some more RAM and maybe an SSD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)